# AWS Lambda time out in 6 seconds

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, nodes, sequelize.js, serverless-framework

I am using the serverless framework with nodejs(Version 4.4) to create AWS lambda functions. The default timeout is 6 seconds for lambda execution. I am connecting to mysql database using sequelize ORM. I see errors like *execution timed out*. Sometimes my code works properly even with this error. But sometimes nothing works after this timeout error. Its really hard for me make sense out of this timeout.  I am afraid increasing the timeout will incur more charge.

Comment: You are charged only for execution time, not configured time. Increase the time and see if that helps.

Comment: You can try increasing it for a small duration, to figure out if the issue is with lambda or code. Increase it to, suppose 10s for a day, observe the behaviour. If there are still timeouts, increase it to 5 min, observe again.

Comment: MySQL connection/query could be taking time. Before you try to increase the timeout review the code once. See if there are optimizations to be made. If there are none, you have nothing left but to increase the timeout. The run time for lambda function must be deterministic.

Comment: I think you are opening but not properly closing the database connections in your handler. How are you opening and closing your database connections?

Answer (score 2):

If you are seeing errors like 'execution timed out' than you are probably cutting the execution of your Lambdas with a too low timeout.

There might be several reasons for this:

- The initialization of the container can be slow, this should only occur for the first call of container. If you have a low memory setting and load lots of libraries it can happen that it takes quite a while(usually this shouldn't be a problem with node)
- Connecting to a database can be slow
- If you reuse database connections, it's possible that they are stale and this can lead to a timeout.
- Your database queries may be slow.

To mitigate the problem you should temporarily add some logging to your Lambda and increase the timeout, so that you can figure out what actually takes so long. Unless you are already a heavy Lambda user you are unlikely to use up your [400.000 free GB-seconds](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/pricing/) a month. If you run your Lambdas with 128 MB this equates to 3.200.000 seconds per month / 103.225 seconds per day / 28.5 hours per day. Try to test with higher memory settings as well, depending on case this can even reduce the total GB/s consumed.

As others pointed out already you only pay for the time actually used, so if your Lambda finishes faster than the timeout you only pay for the actual time consumed(in 100 ms increments).